# Values,set in auto-layout constraints doesn't match element's position on subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, xcode6

There is a custom UITableViewCell subclass with xib. all elements' constraints are set in IB
[image]

Let's take a look at Test label (UILabel element). It has 3 constraints:
[image]

The **trailing space** to superview(cell's content view) is set to **12**.

The **leading space** to superview is set to **12**

The **top space** to superview is set to **5**

But when I build and run, the real distance between left simulator's margin and label's leading side is **20**! As well for top space - it is more then expected **5px**

[image]

If I give to label long name - it gets resized and trailing space is positioned correctly -exactly to 12px, as expected.

The same situation is with 2 images below test label. While theirs leading spaces are set to 12, in reality they are distanced on 20 px from content view's left margin.

What can be the reason of issue?

Comment: Is your table view have some leading constraint to superview

Comment: If you double click on the constraint to edit it, does it say something like "Superview.trailing Margin" ? If so, you can uncheck the "relative to margin" box in the pull down.

Comment: double click on constraint just show it's properties on the right side

Comment: @Christeena John yes, tableview has constraint to leading space to superview with 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default in iOS 8 there is an 8px padding for margins (A view's margin property is UIEdgeInset with 8px padding for all four sides). When you set 12px for leading constrain the margin's 8px padding also will be added to the constrain, thats why your leading constrain is 20px.

Uncheck the "**Relative to Margin**" option for the leading constrain to fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: That's it!Thank you.What is the common practice in this case? Always uncheck this, or just "keep in mind" that 8px margin while building interface from psd-sheets?

Comment: Margin property is available for all the UIView subclasses. But only on UITableViewCell it is set as default. Apple uses the 8px margin in the default apps. It is consistent through out the OS. 
If you are displaying a list of text, you can keep the default margin in mind. For custom cells of course, you can ignore the consistency :)